# Multiple Edits should not end up in Multiple +2's

Tags: feature-request, reputation, editing, suggested-edits

I realised, when editing a post a second time, I got an additional +2 rep. Does this make sense?

I think it's ok once. Is it possible to restrict it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think that is a problem, as you are improving the post.

If you are worried about gaming to increase reputation: after you reach a certain reputation, you are able to make edits without needing approval, and at that point, you stop getting the +2.

And, you do need approval before that.